# Dynamic EBS Volume Creation as part of EC2 Module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a module that I'm using to build EC2, and I'm having trouble creating EBS volumes. I would like to be able to define my EBS volume information as part of my variables.tf, and pass that into my module. With the current code, I can see the parameters being read, but they do not pass.

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│   on modules/vm-deploy/main.tf line 19, in resource "aws_instance" "ec2_instance":
│   19:         device_name      = ebs_block_device.value.ebs_name
│     │ ebs_block_device.value is "/dev/sdb"
│ 
│ Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).
╵

│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│   on modules/vm-deploy/main.tf line 19, in resource "aws_instance" "ec2_instance":
│   19:         device_name      = ebs_block_device.value.ebs_name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ ebs_block_device.value is "100"
│ 
│ Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).
```

variables.tf

```
variable "instances_subnet_1" {
  description = "A complex object that multiple virtual machines."
  type = map(object({
    ami= string
    instance_type= string
    private_ip= string
    subnet_id= string
    vpc_security_group_ids = list(string)
    blockdisks= map(string)
    root_size= string
  }))
  default = {
    "ec2-resource" = {
    ami= "ami-win"
    instance_type= "t3.large"
    private_ip= "10.0.109.4"
    subnet_id= ""
    vpc_security_group_ids = [""]
    root_size= "50"
    blockdisks= {
      "ebs_name"      = "/dev/sdb"
      "ebs_size"      = "100"
    }
}
```

module main.tf

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2_instance" {
    ami= var.ami
    iam_instance_profile= var.iam_instance_role
    instance_type= var.instance_type
    private_ip= var.private_ip
    subnet_id= var.subnet_id
    vpc_security_group_ids= var.vpc_security_group_ids
    dynamic "ebs_block_device" {
    for_each = var.blockdisks
    iterator = ebs_block_device
      content {
        delete_on_termination = false
        encrypted= true
        device_name= ebs_block_device.value.ebs_name
        volume_size= ebs_block_device.value.ebs_size
        volume_type= "gp2"
      }
    }
    root_block_device {
    delete_on_termination = false
    encrypted= true
    volume_size= var.root_size
    volume_type= "gp2"
    }
}
```

main.tf

```
module "vm-deploy-subnet-1" {
  source= "./modules/vm-deploy"
  for_each= var.instances_subnet_1
  ami= each.value.ami
  iam_instance_role= each.value.iam_instance_role
  instance_type= each.value.instance_type
  private_ip= each.value.private_ip
  subnet_id= data.aws_subnet.subnet_1.id
  vpc_security_group_ids= [data.aws_security_group.default.id]
  root_size= each.value.root_size
  blockdisks= each.value.blockdisks
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over a map of strings. You want to iterate over a map of objects instead.

In your `variables.tf` make the following changes:

```
variable "instances_subnet_1" {
  type        = map(object({
    // skipped unchanged
    blockdisks = map(object({
      ebs_name = string
      ebs_size = string
    }))
  }))
  default = {
    ec2-resource = {
      // skipped unchanged
      blockdisks = {
        disk1 = {
          ebs_name = "/dev/sdb"
          ebs_size = "100"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Once again you killed it, Anton! Thank you.